# Scala compiler throws annotation argument needs to be a constant error on constant argument

Tags: scala, annotations

I'm using the following annotation parameter shipped with Spark-SQL:

```
@SQLUserDefinedType(udt = ActionUDT.CLAZZ)
trait Action extends ActionLike {
...implementation
}
```

Where `ActionUDT.CLAZZ` is defined as a constant val:

```
object ActionUDT extends ActionUDT {
  final val CLAZZ: Class[_ <: ActionUDT] = this.getClass
}
```

But I got the following compiler error:

```
Error:(25, 37) annotation argument needs to be a constant; found: ActionUDT.clazz
@SQLUserDefinedType(udt = ActionUDT.clazz)
                                    ^
```

Why does it produce such a false alarm? Is it a bug? I'm using Scala 2.10.5

Answer (score 2):

When a parameter of type `Class[_]` is expected in an annotation, using `classOf[]` worked for me. In your case you can try

```
@SQLUserDefinedType(udt = classOf[ActionUDT])
```

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this problem.  Turns out, `scaladoc` doesn't even try to see if the given expression eventually returns a constant.  So in my case the error was:

```
error: annotation argument needs to be a constant; found "someString1".+("someString2")
```

In code, this was simply concatenating `someString1` and `someString2`. .  Changing the code so there's no string concatenation at all fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A `class` is not a constant object as defined here. A constant is .. well .. a constant as in a numeric or string literal.