# Openapi swagger documentation generates references

Tags: scala, swagger, openapi, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

I have a couple enumerations in an annotated object like:

```scala
@Schema(description = "Request description")
case class Request(
   @Schema(description = "Enum1 description")
   field2: Enum1,
  
   @Schema(description = "Enum2 description")
   field2: Enum2
)
```

where the enums are defined as:

```scala
sealed trait Enum1 extends EnumEntry
object Enum1 extends Enum[Enum1] {
   case object Value1 extends Enum1
   case object Value2 extends Enum1
}

sealed trait Enum2 extends EnumEntry
object Enum2 extends Enum[Enum2] {
   case object Value3 extends Enum2
   case object Value4 extends Enum2
}
```

Using Openapi3, I can generate a swagger documentation. My problem is that say `Enum1` and `Enum2` are translated differently, as in:

```json
"field1":{
    "enum":["Value1","Value2"],
    "type":"string"
},

"field2":{
  "$ref":"#/components/schemas/Enum2"
}

/* ... */

"Enum2":{
  "description":"Enum2 description",
  "type":"object"
}
```

I want `Enum2` to be documented the same as `Enum1`, so with the actual enumeration values. Is there any way to force this, or any explanation on why this might happen? Two enumerations are basically the same as in the example.

Comment: Which library do you use to generate the OpenAPI? You might get more feedback by opening an issue/question on their GitHub/Slack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I managed to solve it by adding the `implementation` argument to the `@Schema` annotation. Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59282771/swagger-openapi-annotations-v3-use-enum-values-in-swagger-annotations) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37502659/scala-compiler-throws-annotation-argument-needs-to-be-a-constant-error-on-consta):

```scala
@Schema(description = "Request description")
case class Request(
   @Schema(
     implementation = classOf[Enum1],
     description = "Enum1 description"
   )
   field1: Enum1,
)
```